# “An orange is more more delicious than an apple than grapes.”

Tags: comparison

“An orange is more more delicious than an apple than grapes.”

Delicacy level

1. Orange: 10
2. Apple: 5
3. Grapes: 3

An orange is 5 degrees more delicious than an apple. (10-5=5)
An orange is 2 degrees more 5 degrees more delicious than an apple than grapes. (10-5=5>3)

Normally, why don’t we say “an orange is [more [more delicious than an apple] than grapes]” in English even though it’s an obvious fact?

Comment: It's quite unnecessary to repeat _more_. Which fruit you prefer is a matter of opinion., not 'an obvious fact'. You could say "I find oranges more delicious than apples, and much more delicious than grapes."

Answer (score -2):

Oh, here must be a joke "when a programmer starts to learn a language"

Well, there're couple of couples of ways to say that so as it doesn't sound awkward

> Apple is more delicious than grapes, but orange is the most delicious of them all / orange is more delicious than both apple and grapes

> Apple is more delicious than grapes, but orange is more delicious than apple

> Although apple is more delicious than grapes, it's less delicious than orange

> Out of apple, orange and grapes, orange is the most delicious and apple goes second

And so on

Comment: Thank you, but why did we both get a downvote?

Comment: 'apple' and 'orange' in this context need to be pluralized "apples are more delicious..."